# Multiple url exists check

Tags: php, shell, curl

I have around 100k URLS in a database and I want to check if all the URLS are valid. I tried with PHP and curl but its very slow and gives script timeout. Is there any better way to do this using some other shell script?

so far I tried this:

```
// By default get_headers uses a GET request to fetch the headers. If you
// want to send a HEAD request instead, you can do so using a stream context:
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    )
);
$headers = get_headers('http://example.com');
```

It's running in for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of latency in servers replying, so this problem lends itself to parallelising. Try splitting the list into a number of sublists and running scripts in parallel, each one processing a different list.

Try looking at the `split` command to generate the lists.

So, you will get something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
split -l 1000 urllist.txt tmpurl       # split bigfile into 1000 line subfiles called tmpurl*
for p in tmpurl*                       # for all tmpurl* files
do
   # Start a process to check the URLs in that list
   echo start checking file $p in background &    
done
wait                                   # till all are finished
```

Where I have put "start checking file $p in background" you would need to supply a simple PHP or shell script that takes a filename as parameter (or reads from its stdin) and does the checking in a for loop of all the URLs in the file however you are already doing it.

**Extra Information:**

Just for fun, I made a list of 1,000 URLs and `curl`ed headers from each of them, with `curl -I -s`. In the sequential case, it took 4 minutes 19 seconds. When I used the above script to split the 1,000 URLs into sub-lists of 100 in each file and started 10 processes, the entire test took 22 seconds - so a 12x speedup. Splitting the list into sublists of 50 URLs, resulted in 20 processes that all completed in 14 seconds. So, as I said, the problem is readily parallelisable.

Comment: you mean creating multiple scripts passing different url slots?

Comment: Yes, see updated answer. This would create 100 processes and each one would check 1000 URLs using your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mechanize python module to visit websites and take response from it

Answer (score 0):

my bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

###############################################
# mailto: ggerman@gmail.com
# checkurls
# https://github.com/ggerman/checkurls
# require curl
###############################################

url() {
  cat urls.csv | 
  replace  | 
  show
}

replace() {
  tr ',' ' '
}

show() {
  awk '{print $1}'
}

url | \
while read CMD; do
  echo $CMD
  curl -Is $CMD | head -n 1
done
```